# Does HID support two way data communication?

Tags: hid

I'm building a HID device. Does anyone know if the HID protocol supports two way communication -- can the host send commands to the device to, for example, turn on or off LEDs, power off, etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. E.g. it's possible to control a monitor (select its video input, select the color mode and so on) with [hidmon](http://random-internet-node.de/projekte/hidmon).